# Installation of tflite c++ on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: c++, tensorflow, installation, tensorflow-lite, ubuntu-20.04

I want to install tflite c++ on my ubuntu 20.04 but I am having some issues regarding installation. I got to know that I can only build this by using cmake or bazel but unfortunately both of them were not working for me. As cmake taking alot of RAM so it gets crash every time when it reaches to 96% during build and bazel is also giving some error during build. After using this command.

> bazel build -c opt //tensorflow/lite:libtensorflowlite.so

It gave me this
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4chcC.png). I have also checked that numpy is [available](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKg2h.png).
I was following this [video](https://youtu.be/He2p2JLpYC0).
Can anyone please send me the link of github where tflite c++ is available for ubuntu or any other link from where i can install this easily. As I am new in this. Your comments and suggestions will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Here is the error which I am getting.

```
bazel build -c opt //tensorflow/lite:libtensorflowlite.so
Extracting Bazel installation...
Starting local Bazel server and connecting to it...
INFO: Options provided by the client:
  Inherited 'common' options: --isatty=1 --terminal_columns=91
INFO: Reading rc options for 'build' from /home/umer/Downloads/tensorflow-2.4.2/.bazelrc:
  Inherited 'common' options: --experimental_repo_remote_exec
INFO: Reading rc options for 'build' from /home/umer/Downloads/tensorflow-2.4.2/.bazelrc:
  'build' options: --apple_platform_type=macos --define framework_shared_object=true --define open_source_build=true --java_toolchain=//third_party/toolchains/java:tf_java_toolchain --host_java_toolchain=//third_party/toolchains/java:tf_java_toolchain --define=tensorflow_enable_mlir_generated_gpu_kernels=0 --define=use_fast_cpp_protos=true --define=allow_oversize_protos=true --spawn_strategy=standalone -c opt --announce_rc --define=grpc_no_ares=true --noincompatible_remove_legacy_whole_archive --noincompatible_prohibit_aapt1 --enable_platform_specific_config --config=short_logs --config=v2
INFO: Reading rc options for 'build' from /home/umer/Downloads/tensorflow-2.4.2/.tf_configure.bazelrc:
  'build' options: --host_force_python=PY2 --action_env PYTHON_BIN_PATH=/usr/bin/python --action_env PYTHON_LIB_PATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages --python_path=/usr/bin/python --config=xla --action_env TF_CONFIGURE_IOS=0
INFO: Found applicable config definition build:short_logs in file /home/umer/Downloads/tensorflow-2.4.2/.bazelrc: --output_filter=DONT_MATCH_ANYTHING
INFO: Found applicable config definition build:v2 in file /home/umer/Downloads/tensorflow-2.4.2/.bazelrc: --define=tf_api_version=2 --action_env=TF2_BEHAVIOR=1
INFO: Found applicable config definition build:xla in file /home/umer/Downloads/tensorflow-2.4.2/.bazelrc: --define=with_xla_support=true
INFO: Found applicable config definition build:linux in file /home/umer/Downloads/tensorflow-2.4.2/.bazelrc: --copt=-w --host_copt=-w --define=PREFIX=/usr --define=LIBDIR=$(PREFIX)/lib --define=INCLUDEDIR=$(PREFIX)/include --define=PROTOBUF_INCLUDE_PATH=$(PREFIX)/include --cxxopt=-std=c++14 --host_cxxopt=-std=c++14 --config=dynamic_kernels
INFO: Found applicable config definition build:dynamic_kernels in file /home/umer/Downloads/tensorflow-2.4.2/.bazelrc: --define=dynamic_loaded_kernels=true --copt=-DAUTOLOAD_DYNAMIC_KERNELS
DEBUG: Rule 'io_bazel_rules_go' indicated that a canonical reproducible form can be obtained by modifying arguments shallow_since = "1557349968 -0400"
DEBUG: Repository io_bazel_rules_go instantiated at:
  no stack (--record_rule_instantiation_callstack not enabled)
Repository rule git_repository defined at:
  /home/umer/.cache/bazel/_bazel_umer/ed358c98f40a3a8df15c688cf3579422/external/bazel_tools/tools/build_defs/repo/git.bzl:195:18: in <toplevel>
INFO: Repository local_config_python instantiated at:
  no stack (--record_rule_instantiation_callstack not enabled)
Repository rule python_configure defined at:
  /home/umer/Downloads/tensorflow-2.4.2/third_party/py/python_configure.bzl:294:20: in <toplevel>
ERROR: An error occurred during the fetch of repository 'local_config_python':
   Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/umer/Downloads/tensorflow-2.4.2/third_party/py/python_configure.bzl", line 267
        _create_local_python_repository(<1 more arguments>)
    File "/home/umer/Downloads/tensorflow-2.4.2/third_party/py/python_configure.bzl", line 213, in _create_local_python_repository
        _get_numpy_include(<2 more arguments>)
    File "/home/umer/Downloads/tensorflow-2.4.2/third_party/py/python_configure.bzl", line 187, in _get_numpy_include
        execute(repository_ctx, <3 more arguments>)
    File "/home/umer/Downloads/tensorflow-2.4.2/third_party/remote_config/common.bzl", line 217, in execute
        fail(<1 more arguments>)
Problem getting numpy include path.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named numpy
Is numpy installed?
ERROR: Analysis of target '//tensorflow/lite:libtensorflowlite.so' failed; build aborted: Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/umer/Downloads/tensorflow-2.4.2/third_party/py/python_configure.bzl", line 267
        _create_local_python_repository(<1 more arguments>)
    File "/home/umer/Downloads/tensorflow-2.4.2/third_party/py/python_configure.bzl", line 213, in _create_local_python_repository
        _get_numpy_include(<2 more arguments>)
    File "/home/umer/Downloads/tensorflow-2.4.2/third_party/py/python_configure.bzl", line 187, in _get_numpy_include
        execute(repository_ctx, <3 more arguments>)
    File "/home/umer/Downloads/tensorflow-2.4.2/third_party/remote_config/common.bzl", line 217, in execute
        fail(<1 more arguments>)
Problem getting numpy include path.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named numpy
Is numpy installed?
INFO: Elapsed time: 87.176s
INFO: 0 processes.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (11 packages loaded, 19 targets configured)
    currently loading: @bazel_tools//tools/jdk
    Fetching @local_execution_config_python; Restarting.
    Fetching @rules_java; fetching
    Fetching @io_bazel_rules_docker; fetching
    Fetching @go_sdk; fetching
```

Comment: please show errors and commands as text not images

Comment: I have include the text kindly check

Answer (score 0):

I could successfully install tflite c++ on ubuntu 20.04. I have used  the following commands in a conda virtual environment. As per the [tested build configurations](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#linux) `TF v2.4` is compatible with `Bazel 3.1.0`. Hence I have used Bazel 3.1.0 to install tflite c++.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade

#install python
sudo apt-get install python

#set environment variable "/usr/bin/python" in my case
export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/python

#Install the TensorFlow pip package dependencies
pip install -U --user pip numpy wheel packaging requests opt_einsum
pip install -U --user keras_preprocessing --no-deps

#Install Bazel and move file to bin folder so that it will be available system wide
chmod +x bazel-3.1.0-linux-x86_64
sudo mv bazel-3.1.0-linux-x86_64 ./.local/bin/bazel

cd ./.local/bin
#Extract bazel installation
bazel

#Check bazel version
bazel --version

#clone tensorflow repo in the same location where Anaconda is installed
cd ~

#clone tensorflow repo
git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow.git

#Download the source code of tensorflow 2.4.2 and unzip it 
cd tensorflow-2.4.2
python ./configure.py
```

It prompts the following:

> Please specify the location of python. [Default is /usr/bin/python3]:

You can press Enter if the default location is ok.

> Do you wish to build TensorFlow with ROCm support? [y/N]: N No ROCm
> support will be enabled for TensorFlow.
>
> Do you wish to build TensorFlow with CUDA support? [y/N]: N No CUDA
> support will be enabled for TensorFlow.
>
> Do you wish to download a fresh release of clang? (Experimental)
> [y/N]: N Clang will not be downloaded.
>
> Please specify optimization flags to use during compilation when bazel
> option "--config=opt" is specified [Default is -Wno-sign-compare]:
>
> Would you like to interactively configure ./WORKSPACE for Android
> builds? [y/N]: N Not configuring the WORKSPACE for Android builds.

I have opted "N" for all the prompts

```
#bazel command to build build tflite library
bazel build -c opt //tensorflow/lite:libtensorflowlite.so
```

You can see the Build successful screenshot below. Thank you!

[image]